# Can't find page on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have a page in wordpress which maps to the `/testimonials` permalink. The page was working fine a couple of days ago, it does not have any special stuff, just an iFrame and a feed.

The problem is that the page cannot be found right now, the link works showing `Error: unrecognized start tag '' in getOutput()` and it doesn't show the header to edit it. Furthermore, when I try to create a new page with the same permalink it won't let me.

I already tried looking for it in Pages, Posts and any other place I could think of.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Remove that iframe and save page - see if this makes any difference

Comment: I can’t even access the edit page functionality, that’s the problem actually